# Implement Access Token and Refresh Token with apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to intercept a request from apollo client to apollo server and return either a different typeDef field or an undefined one without the client resulting in an error.

This is to check the users refresh token if there access token is expired, and send a new access token instead of the nomral query they were expecting.

Here is my code:

Server:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  },
  context: async ({ req, res }) => {
    let isAuthenticated = false;
    // get the user token from the headers
    const authorization = req.get("Authorization");
    if (authorization) {
      let token = req.headers.authorization.replace(/\(/g, "");
      let verifysomething = jwt.verify(
        token,
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        (err, decoded) => {
          console.log("access decoded");
          console.log(decoded);
          if (err) {
            return err;
          }

          return decoded;
        }
      );
      if (verifysomething.message == "jwt expired") {
        let refreshToken = req.headers.cookie.replace(/^[^=]+=/, "");
        let verifyRefresh = jwt.verify(
          refreshToken,
          process.env.JWT_SECRET,
          (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) return err;

            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
              { userId: decoded.userId },
              process.env.JWT_SECRET,
              {
                expiresIn: "20s",
              }
            );
            isAuthenticated = "newAccess";
            return accessToken;
          }
        );
         //end return if now access token but has refresh token
        return { isAuthenticated, res, verifyRefresh };
      }

      let user = await User.findOne({ _id: verifysomething.userId });
      if (user) {
        isAuthenticated = true;

        return {
          isAuthenticated,
          user,
        };
      }
    }

    return { isAuthenticated, res };
  },
});
```

Resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getCartItems: authenticate(
      async (_, { id }) =>
        await cartItem.find({ user: id }).populate("user").populate("item")
    ),
  }}
```

Authenticate:

```
function authenticate(resolver) {
  return function (root, args, context, info) {
    if (context.isAuthenticated == true) {
      return resolver(root, args, context, info);
    } 
    else if ((isAuthenticated = "newAccess")) {
      return context.verifyRefresh;
    }
    throw new Error(`Access Denied!`);
  };
}
```

To clarify, the issue is that a request going to `getCartItems` will be expecting a retun like:

```
  type CartItemPayload {
    item: Item
    user: User
  }
```

but if their access token is expired I would like to just send them a new one first instead.

Now one way I thought to solve this was by adding a new mutation query for refresh token and on each request from the client I can decode the access token jwt to see if it is expired and if so then I make a request to the refreshToken mutation instead of the getCartItems query for example, and that way I would be able to get the expected typeDef return and easily control the data I am receiving.

The problem I see with that is this just feels like a problem that is supposed to be solved on the serverside. I am new to apollo and graphql and am not using an express server for middleware nor am I using redux for middleware on the client side and not sure if what I am trying to achieve is possible this way.

I am open to any solutions or suggestions for this problem, thanks.

Comment: You'd be way better off using an existing OAuth2 implementation instead of poorly inventing your own auth.

Comment: I am doing this project for the intention of learning, however if I needed to ship a real product right now I think that is a great recommendation.